# Laravel 8 - Global Object available throughout application (not just in view files)

Tags: laravel

In my application, users can belong to different accounts and have different roles on those accounts. To determine which account is "current" I am setting a session variable in the `LoginController` in the `authenticated()` method.

`$request->session()->put('account_id', $user->accounts()->first()->id);`

Then, throughout the application I am doing a simple Eloquent query to find an account by ID.

While this "works", I am basically repeating the same exact query in every single Controller, Middleware, etc. The maintainability is suffering and there are duplicate queries showing in Debugbar.

For example, in every controller I am doing:

```
protected $account;

public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware(function($req, $next){
            $this->account = Account::find($req->session()->get('account_id'));
            return $next($req);
        });
   
    }
```

In custom middleware and throughout the entire application, I am essentially doing the same thing - finding Account by ID stored in session.

I understand you can share variable with all views, but I need a way to share with the whole application.

I suppose much in the same way you can get the auth user with `auth()->user`.

What would be the way to do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class to handle this logic. Making it a singleton, to ensure it is the same class you are accessing. So in a provider singleton the class you are gonna create in a second.

```
$this->app->singleton(AccountContext::class);
```

Create the class, where you can set the account in context and get it out.

```
class AccountContext
{
    private $account;

    public function getAccount()
    {
        return $this->account;
    }

    public function setAccount($account)
    {
        $this->account = $account;
    }
}
```

Now set your account in the middleware.

```
$this->middleware(function($req, $next){
    resolve(AccountContext::class)->setAccount(Account::find($req->session()->get('account_id')));

    return $next($req);
});
```

Everywhere in your application you can now access the account, with this snippet.

```
resolve(AccountContext::class)->getAccount();
```

Comment: Would I need to create a new ServiceProvider and put the `$this->app->singleton(AccountContext::class);` in the `register()` method?

Comment: Nope, you can add it to the appserviceprovider

Comment: Thanks. This should work, but for some reason I'm having an issue with different instances being returned. In the login controller, it's the same instance every time if I were to copy the `$foo = resolve(AccountContext::class)` they all have an ID of #1718. But once it goes to the first middleware, it's a new instance (#1754). so `->getAccount()` is null. i will have to debug further

Comment: ensure $this->app->singleton(AccountContext::class); is in the provider and the provider is actually being called, like dd() it. Secondly are you resolving the accountcontext from the container? with app() or resolve() if you use new AccountContext, it will go around the singleton.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Your example says to use `resolve`. Sorry I will have to learn how to use providers and singletons better. I will come back to this

Comment: yes, my example uses resolve, but there is many approaches to using the container, but resolve(AccountContext::class) will use the container, but new AccountContext() wont :) Learning the container, is well worth the reading time of the laravel documentation part for that.

Comment: I wasn't using `new AccountContext()`, but I think what i didn't realize was that this instance is only available per request. so each request has a different singleton. what I'm really trying to do is essentially be able to call something like `auth()->account` throughout the app and not duplicate any logic. appreciate you taking the time. I will do some studying.

Comment: But since it is saved in the session, each call should have the same account? if the session keeps the same